# How close to -3 do we have to take $x$ such that $\frac{1}{(x+3)^4} > 10000$

Tags: calculus

First
$$\frac{1}{(x+3)^4} > 10000 \implies (x+3)^4 < 0.0001$$

We must find $x$ sufficiently close to $-3$, so $|x+3| < \delta $ for some $\delta > 0 $.

$$|x+3|^4 = (x+3)^4 < \delta ^ 4 \implies \delta = 0.1 $$

I feel as though i have not deduced this result correctly. 
Could I have come comments on my method please.

Comment: No, that's correct.

Comment: You've proved that $(x + 3)^{-4} > 10000$ implies that $|x - 3| < 0.1$, which is not what the question is asking you to prove.

Comment: I need to add that, if we take the distance between -3 and x to be less than 0.1, then the result follows. Is that what is required?

Answer (score 2):

Your method is correct but I would add some details. Some of that is to show that your $\delta$ works: you worked backwards to find the $\delta$ but your main proof will want the other direction.

$$\begin{align}
0<|x+3|<0.1 &\implies 0<(x+3)^4<\frac 1{10000} \\
 &\implies \frac 1{(x+3)^4}>10000
\end{align}$$